# When to use durable Queue in RabbitMq cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq

I read about Durable Queue that it remain if RabbitMQ goes down and we didn't lost the our Message And Queues.

In this [Article](https://www.cnblogs.com/popsuper1982/p/3800419.html) i read that in cluster if a Node goes down and its Queue was durable this is impossible to recreate the queues and we got 404 Not_Found error! so its a bad situation. so when is better to define a durable Queue?

Answer (score 0):

Durable queues insure that when the node comes back online the previous queue state is restored back .

It is non durable queue which looses the data if the node goes down , there is however an option to is lazy queues which immediately writes the data to disk once they get a message in the queue. Important to mention that the queues are all in HA mode i.e. they get replicated across all the nodes

In real world , the cluster is load balanced behind a hardware or software based Load Balancer which connects to the next available node in case the primary RabbitMQ node goes down

Comment: Thanks For answer, but i consider a situation when related Node failed and its publisher and consumer can not create queue so the application does not work properly. in this situation what we should do?

Comment: So you should put an NLB in front of the cluster , the moment a node goes down the NLB should be directing your traffic to the secondary nodes. This will enable your application to continue to bind to queues and exchanges and subscribe / publish as required.

Comment: See this link for more info , depending on your requirements you can modify the configuration https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2017/04/03/rabbitmq-high-available-cluster-haproxy-docker/

Comment: When  we use load balancer and  the Node with durable quese goes down. We didn't get 404 error?

Comment: Hey @pejman so I guess that is a good thing that Node went down and load balancer redirected the request to next in line... No..